# time data '2018-06-19 11:21:13.311' does not match format

Tags: python, time

Using python, I am trying to read a date/time format ergo 2018-06-19 11:21:13.311, which returns an error:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-06-19 11:21:13.311' does not match format
'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%%'
```

I have tried removing the .%%, but the program returns an unconverted data error message. Does anyone know what the .311 is? And how I can read it?

Answer (score 6):

Your datetime string is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

Try:

```
import datetime
s = "2018-06-19 11:21:13.311"
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') )
```

**Output:**

```
2018-06-19 11:21:13.311000
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)**

Comment: Rakesh it works 2018-06-19 11:31:44.602000
2018-06-19 11:31:44.602000
2018-06-19 11:31:44.602000
2018-06-19 11:31:44.602000
======== end read Nexpose ==========

Answer (score 2):

To avoid these kind of errors you can use `dateutil.parser`, which can automatically guess the correct format string. You can install it by doing `pip install python-dateutil`

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("2018-06-19 11:21:13.311")
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 19, 11, 21, 13, 311000)
```